# Difference between date objects in php

Tags: php, datetime

I need to to find the difference between two date objects in php

I tried this:

```
if(strtotime($current)>strtotime($LastUpdated))
{
    $diff=strtotime($current) - strtotime($LastUpdated);
}
else
{
    $diff=strtotime($LastUpdated) - strtotime($current);
}
```

This gave me junk values.

I also tries this

```
$diff=date_diff(new DateTime($current),new DateTime($LastUpdated));
```

This is giving me zero.

How do I go about finding the difference?

Comment: What kind of _junk values_ did you get? In the first code, `$diff` should be the difference in seconds.

Comment: What type of objects are `$current` and `$LastUpdated`? Your question says _date objects_, but `strtotime()` expects a string.

Comment: $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. The value is indeed in seconds. Didn't realise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Manual is your friend. - http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
With examples for Object-Oriented and Procedural programming.

pasted from the link above:

OOP:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Procedural:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

and the result will be:

```
+2 days
```

have fun :)

Comment: @Barmar you should look at the link. you have the examples needed to understand the solution you need and how diff works between two dates.

Comment: I don't care what's in the link. It could be the perfect answer to their question, it's still not an acceptable way to answer questions on SO>

Comment: If the OP were competent to figure things out from examples in documentation, he wouldn't have asked a question like this.

Comment: @Barmar so you cal OP incompetent, and you don't give him the tools to become competent. you just throw the answers to they needs. - you give the fish instead of teaching him how to fish

Comment: You can do BOTH. Explain how to fix his problem, and point him to the documentation that provides more details.

Comment: @Barmar, btw.. i've added the example to find the diff from two dates. hope you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

I think this is better for you.